# Automating Ansible Playbook Execution with Encrypted sudo_password.yml: Handling Vault Password securely

Tags: docker, ansible

I feel not very satisfied with one of the ansible features.

For my scenario I want to execute a playbook on my managed-node to install e.g nginx.

Now I have on my control node following playbook.yml:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install Packages
      apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes state=latest
      loop: ['nginx', 'vim']
      tags: ['setup']

    - name: Copy index page
      copy:
        src: index.html
        dest: /var/www/html/index.html
        owner: www-data
        group: www-data
        mode: '0644'
      tags: ['update', 'sync']
```

and my hosts.yml

```yaml
---
ungrouped:
  hosts:
    testserver:
      ansible_host: managed.node.ip
      ansible_user: exampleuser
      ansible_become_pass: '{{sudo_password}}'
      ansible_ss_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
vault_password_file = vault_pass.txt
```

To execute the playbook on my managed node, I have a decrypted `sudo_password.yml` on my control node.

Now there are several options to execute it correctly:

Method 1:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml --extra-vars '@sudo_pass.yml' ansible-receiver_playbook.yml`

Method 2:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml --ask-vault-pass --extra-vars '@sudo_pass.yml' ansible-receiver_playbook.yml`

Method 1 uses the `vault_pass.txt` which is defined in my ansible.cfg.

Method 2 asks me interactively to input my vault password.

Now I have some issues with automating this process. Method 1 would work e.g scheduled as a cronjob. Method 2 wouldnt work, since there is an input required.

Method 1 feels kind of wrong to me, since I dont want to save my `vault-password` in plain text just to decrypt my encrypted `sudo_password.yml`

Is there something crucial I've missed so far?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something crucial I've missed so far?

It depends on how do you plan to execute your playbook. A typical environment could be a CI/CD server or a K8S instance. Both have their tools to store the secrets and mount them temporarily into a place where they could be securely accessed by your playbook.

Also, have a look at [Storing passwords in third-party tools with vault password client scripts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/vault_managing_passwords.html#storing-passwords-in-third-party-tools-with-vault-password-client-scripts) in Ansible Vault documentation.

Comment: I want to use some of them in my Gitlab CI/CD but others I want to be executed by cron. so in my case it depends on the playbook itself

Comment: Well, you don't have any options except the ones listed in the documentation, so you'll just need to adjust your environment selecting the option that suits you better. "By cron" is not an environment, do you mean you have a dedicated control node that is not part of your CI/CD stack? If so, you will probably need to have different Ansible configurations for this node and for Gitlab. `ansible.cfg` is not the only way to achieve that - for example, you can override some settings using the corresponding environment variables.

Comment: Alright thanks. I think you are right and I have to do some adjustments to my infrastructure. I meant that on my control node some playbooks should've been executed by cron to collect some stuff on managed notes etc.
But thanks for your hints